# Given a JSON value, how do I get the parent's sibling value?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net

I have a .NET Core 3.1 C# application reading the following JSON doc:

```
{
  "info": {
    "_postman_id": "b"
  },
  "item": [
    {
      "name": "GetEntityById via APIM",
      "item": [
        {
          "name": "Call 1",
          "url": {
            "raw": "urlforcall1"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Call 2",
          "url": {
            "raw": "urlforcall2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to select the value for each `item\item\name` and each `item\item\url\raw`.

So, I'd like to end up with `"Call 1":"urlforcall1"` and `"Call 2":"urlforcall2"`.

I've been playing around and can grab the value from the `raw` token with the following:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var urls = jObject.SelectTokens("..raw");
```

How can I grab the value from its parent's sibling, `name`?

Comment: Are you not wanting to serialize the JSON into a C# object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may flatten inner `item` array using [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1) method into one sequence (since outer `item` is also an array), then get `name` and `raw` values directly by key

```cs
var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

var innerItems = jObject["item"]?.SelectMany(t => t["item"]);
foreach (var item in innerItems)
{
    var name = item["name"];
    var raw = item["url"]?["raw"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code will help you

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = @"
            {
                'info': {
                     '_postman_id': 'b'
                },
                'item': [
                {
                     'name': 'GetEntityById via APIM',
                     'item': [
                     {
                          'name': 'Call 1',
                          'url': {
                          'raw': 'urlforcall1',
                     }
                 },
                 {
                     'name': 'Call 2',
                     'url': {
                     'raw': 'urlforcall2',
                 }
             }
         ]
     }
 ]
            }";

            dynamic d = JObject.Parse(json);

            foreach(var item in d.item)
            {
                foreach(var innerItem in item.item)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"'{innerItem.name}' : '{innerItem.url.raw}'");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can be tested here https://dotnetfiddle.net/xDr90O

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, if you have a `JToken` you can navigate upward from there using the `Parent` property.  In your case you would need to use it four times to get to the level you want:

- The parent of the `JValue` representing the call URL string is a `JProperty` with the name `raw`
- The parent of that `JProperty` is a `JObject`
- The parent of that `JObject` is a `JProperty` with the name `url`
- The parent of that `JProperty` is a `JObject`, which also contains the `name` property

From there you can navigate back down using indexer syntax to get the value of `name`.

So, you would end up with this:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

foreach (JToken raw in jObject.SelectTokens("..raw"))
{
    string callName = (string)raw.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent["name"];
    string urlForCall = (string)raw;
}
```