# Getting json attributes based on condition

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have following json data. I need to get the LastModifiedDate field if I pass ID as a parameter.

ie,

GetLatestModifiedData("101") => This should return "2022-04-04T17:30:15.8609796Z"

GetLatestModifiedData("102") => This should return "2018-05-05T16:36:41.1106642Z"

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

```
{
    "ProductImportData": {
        "ProductsToImport": [{
                "ImportMode": "Update",
                "DateInfo": {
                    "LastModifiedDate": "2022-04-04T17:30:15.8609796Z"
                },
                "Values": [{
                    "Name": "ID",
                    "ValuesByLocale": {
                        "en-US": "101"
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                "ImportMode": "Update",
                "DateInfo": {
                    "LastModifiedDate": "2018-05-05T16:36:41.1106642Z"
                },
                "Values": [{
                    "Name": "ID",
                    "ValuesByLocale": {
                        "en-US": "102"
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
}



  public class DateInfo
    {
        public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductImportData
   {
        public List<ProductsToImport> ProductsToImport { get; set; }
}

public class ProductsToImport
{
    public string ImportMode { get; set; }
    public DateInfo DateInfo { get; set; }
    public List<Value> Values { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public ProductImportData ProductImportData { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ValuesByLocale ValuesByLocale { get; set; }
}

public class ValuesByLocale
{
    [JsonProperty("en-US")]
    public string EnUS { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please check this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61431603/8763644). You need to en-us field parents' parent's sibling child. You can do it similar the that post.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;


ProductImportData productImportData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json).ProductImportData;

DateTime lastModifiedDate = GetLatestModifiedData(productImportData,"102");

public static DateTime GetLatestModifiedData(ProductImportData 
productImportData, string valueId)
{

    return productImportData.ProductsToImport
           .Where(pti => pti.Values.Any(v => v.ValuesByLocale.EnUS == valueId))
           .Select(pti => pti.DateInfo.LastModifiedDate)
           .FirstOrDefault();
}
```